# How to multiplex a video file and audio file in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am capturing the audio and video of the user to server disk. I am saving the video and audio separately. Now i want to `multiplex` both audio and video and save it as a single file in c#. 
How can i able to do this in asp.net c#. I have searched for the implementation but i didn't get any sufficient code. Is there any methods directly in c# or we can include any other `dll` files. How can i do that using C#

Answer (score 0):

It depends somewhat on what container format you want, but a good open source tool you can use  is [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html).

Btw, this question is quite similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694793/how-to-implement-video-and-audio-merger-program).

Edit; I have not tried this library out myself, but it might be what you are looking for: [A Simple C# Wrapper for the AviFile library](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7388/A-Simple-C-Wrapper-for-the-AviFile-Library)

Comment: I have seen the `ffmpeg`. But i didn't understand any thing there. Where we can find the `dll`. The related code and other things

Comment: It is a set of console programs that you can invoke from your code using System.Diagnostics.Process class.

Comment: How can i add that to my project

Comment: There seems to be a confusion of ideas here. Step 1; get the ffmpeg bundle. Step 2; Do the muxing manually using a console window. Step 3; Duplicate this in your program using the process class.

After that you can start moving files around and change things to the way you want them.